# postgresql docker replications

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm relatively new to dockers, but I'm kind of wondering whether is it possible for me to create two master-slave postgres containers. I can do it on virtual machines, but I'm a bit confused on the one in docker.

If it's possible can someone please point me to right directions? 
I have tried to docker exec -it, but all the files are all missing and I cannot edit the files inside.

Comment: Try https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/blob/master/docker-compose-replication.yml.  Just do `docker-compose up -d` after saving that file as `docker-compose.yml`, and you should have two containers up and running in a master-slave setup

Comment: You are a miracle worker. Can you please post it below so I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are new to Docker, and you wish to get up and running quickly, you can try using [Bitnami's images](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/blob/master/docker-compose-replication.yml), which allow you to specify a `POSTGRESQL_REPLICATION_MODE` environment variable, which will allow you to designate a container as a standby/slave.

Just save their `docker-compose-replication.yml` as `docker-compose.yml` in the director of your choice, run `docker-compose up -d`, and it will pull the necessary image and set everything up for you quickly.

However, I would highly encourage you to tinker on your own to learn how Docker works.  Specifically, you could just use the [community Postgres image](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres), and then write your own `entrypoint.sh` file (along with any additional helper files as necessary), and customize the setup to your requirements.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: I have used Bitnami's image but my use case needs to pause streaming, and this command is only possible if one has root access. But Bitnami's images don't allow root access, can you please guide me in this regard?